# Wordpress issue with footer

Tags: wordpress, footer

I've been trying to turn my simple html/css site into a wordpress site. my big issue which no one seem to be able to solve appears in my footer. The footer is pretty much ignoring everything and just staying in the top of the site ( like it was a part of my header). All my files is split into 3 files. A header.php a footer.php and the page.php (one for each site).

Header!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

    <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />

        <?php if (is_search()) { ?>
           <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /> 
        <?php } ?>

        <title>
               <?php
                  if (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {
                     single_tag_title("Tag Archive for &quot;"); echo '&quot; - '; }
                  elseif (is_archive()) {
                     wp_title(''); echo ' Archive - '; }
                  elseif (is_search()) {
                     echo 'Search for &quot;'.wp_specialchars($s).'&quot; - '; }
                  elseif (!(is_404()) && (is_single()) || (is_page())) {
                     wp_title(''); echo ' - '; }
                  elseif (is_404()) {
                     echo 'Not Found - '; }
                  if (is_home()) {
                     bloginfo('name'); echo ' - '; bloginfo('description'); }
                  else {
                      bloginfo('name'); }
                  if ($paged>1) {
                     echo ' - page '. $paged; }
               ?>
        </title>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />

        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

        <?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>


        <?php wp_head(); ?>

    </head>

    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>


                        <div id="Menu" ></div>
                                            <div id="Mainbody">
                                                    <div id="Portfolio"><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a> </div>
                                                    <div id="Slogan"><a href="index.html"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></a></div>
                                                                            <div id="nav-menu">
                                                                                        <?php $defaults = array(
        'theme_location'  => '',
        'menu'            => '', 
        'container'       => 'div', 
        'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container', 
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => 'menu', 
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
        ); ?>

    <?php wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); ?>
                                                                                </div>
                                                   <div class="Box"> 
                                                            <div id="Mainindhold">
```

page!

```
  <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="Arbejde">  

                        <h2>Uddrag af mine webdesigns</h2>
                        <br />
                        <br />

                        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                       <?php $key='link'; $custom = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>
                       <?php $key2='brugt'; $custom2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key2, true); ?>
                       <?php $key3='linkexternal'; $custom3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key3, true); ?>
                       <?php $billede = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'full'); ?>


     <div class="Raekke">
        <div class="Arbejds_Billede">
                            <a href="<?php echo $custom; ?>"  rel="lightbox">
                            <?php print $billede; ?></a>
        </div>  
                        <div class="Arbejdsbeskrivelse">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                                    <div id="program">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $custom2; ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="Knap"><a href="<?php echo $custom3; ?>"><p>Besøg siden</p></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>



     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php endwhile;
                else:
                ?>
                <?php _e('No posts were fond. Sorry!'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>



    </div>

    <?php get_footer();?>
```

footer !

```
</div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
                &copy;<?php echo date("Y"); echo " "; bloginfo('name'); ?> 4000 Roskilde
            </div>


           <script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-31920214-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </body>

    </html>
```

To be able to see the issue you can go into Tinajohnson.dk and ofcourse look in the top.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the footer functions twice in your page: first here:

```
<?php get_footer();?>
```

and  and here again,

```
<div id="footer">
                &copy;<?php echo date("Y"); echo " "; bloginfo('name'); ?> 4000 Roskilde
            </div>
```

get rid of the second piece and it should work.

Comment: The `header`, `page` and `footer` parts are three separate template pages. The OP's code formatting might not have made this immediately clear.

Comment: As Stealthyninja state its 3 different files. The page file calls the footer.php and the header.php that means page.php calls <?php get_footer();?> to get the footer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS problem; add the following rules to your `#footer`'s CSS:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: Using the position: abolute; doesnt work. It just applys the footer in the middle of the page and just not at the bottom where it is suppose to be.

Comment: @Raelona -- I tested it in Chrome and Firefox (Windows 7) with a local copy I made of your homepage. The `#footer` rules I added as in-line style in order to overwrite what ever was set in your stylesheet(s). Which browser(s) are you using that make it display in the middle of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your stick to bottom of browser always. Use Position Fixed not absolute
css will be for your ID footer Div

```
#footer { position:fixed; bottom:0; width:100%}
```

Comment: I dont want the footer to stick like that.. Its suppose to be in the bottom not be in the bottom of the screen/browser window. This is not the issue.